# Does Here map supports Multi Model transportation system?

Tags: here-api

We are trying to find a solution where map provider support route and cost optimization via different types of carrier.

For example : I need to deliver set of items from Location 'A' - 'D'. Delivery will be done using Truck from Location A to Location B. Further items can be moved via Train, Air or Water to next Location C and Now from C location, Truck can pickup the load and deliver to Location D.

Location A -B -> Using Truck,
Location B - C -> Using Train/Air/Water,
Location C - D -> Using Truck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, our Routing and Fleet Telematics APIs can be used to find the `fastest/shortest/cost optimised` routes for different transport modes: `[car | pedestrian | carHOV | publicTransport | publicTransportTimeTable | truck | bicycle ]`

Please checkout the documentation to learn more:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/introduction.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/index.html